# What does x'0a' mean in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

I'm currently working through the official [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/tests/), and there is some SQL I have never encountered before that goes unexplained. I understand that we're inserting values into the post table, and that for `body` we're inserting either `'test'`, or `x'0a'`, or `'body'`. What does `x'0a'` mean? Is `x` some kind of format specifier? I've googled around but am not finding anything useful.

```
INSERT INTO post (title, body, author_id, created)
VALUES
  ('test title', 'test' || x'0a' || 'body', 1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not in SQL, but some specific dialect of SQL. According to the code in that article it is SQLite. So from [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

This way it is a BLOB literal containing linefeed (LF, newline) character.

> ```
> select 'q' || x'0a' || 'w' as tst
> ```

| tst |
| --- |
| q w |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=37e125cfadeb76d91b06acf3652e2090)*

However, it's SQLite specific (and I don't clearly understand SQLite internals, but in other DBMSes will require implicit type conversion), so you may just place newline in the text which is understandable by any DBMS (and `hex` returns the same code point for it as shown below):

> ```
> select 'q
> w' as tst, hex('
> ') as what_is_newline
> ```
>
> | tst | what_is_newline |
> | --- | --- |
> | q w | 0A |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5619b48f63f0e0c7c61bae0070ff697a)*

Comment: I'd also add that in this context, `||` is not the *or* operator, it is string concatenation

Comment: Note that in recent versions of SQLite, you can write `char(10)` instead, which has the advantage of working in UTF-16-encoded databases (which otherwise would require the newline to be written as `x'000a'`).